# Append/Pass the array values from javascript to HTML Div?

Tags: javascript, html

`var array = []; //In this i have 2 items`

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

In this div id I need to pass the above array elements.

Ho can I do this?

Comment: can you please explain clearly what are you trying to achieve here ?

Comment: atleast share the HTML and script so that we can understand your issue.

Comment: what do you expect your output to look like?

Comment: Check the answer santosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the basic example, how you interact with your DOM with javascript.

```js
var array = [1, 2];

var content = document.getElementById("content");

for(var i=0; i< array.length;i++){
 content.innerHTML += i + '--' + array[i] + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

**Big Note:**
You can also use [Javascript Templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates) if you are looking for passing a lot of other data as well to the View

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById` to get the `id` of the `<div>` and then insert the array as a `string` which will convert to the comma separated value:

```js
var array = ['apple','ball']; //In this i have 2 items

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = array.toString();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You Looking for Something like this ?

```
<div class="dummy" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;border: 1px solid black;"></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var arr = ['1','2'];

        jQuery.each( arr, function( i, val ) {
              jQuery('.dummy').append(val);
              jQuery('.dummy').append("<br>");
        });

});
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/vis143/c1kz0b8o/